# Creating a json object dynamically in groovy

Tags: html, json, groovy

I am retrieving a list of data.

Now i want to create an array in json object from that data

for ex `[{obj1:val1},{obj2:val2}]`

I am getting all the data to be populated in the json from list.
The data that is being retrieved from the list while iterating it is String
Now i need to construct json object using value from list

for ex

```
Iterator<PackageClass> itr=list.iterator()
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
        String package=itr.next().getPackageName()
        String version=itr.next().getVersion()
        }
```

Using package and version i have to generate json object as the list is iterated
PackageClass is a class from a library
getPackageName() and getVersion() are two methods of that class

Comment: so your example there is just a string in some broken format (looks like some toString() from something, that was already JSON in it's first live).  you want to parse this text and provide valid JSON for it?  Could you please also provide the content of `list` (or at least a working part) with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what You're looking for:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

class O {
    def key
    def val
}

def l = [[key:1, val:2] as O, [key:3, val:4] as O]

print JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(l))
```

Comment: i dont have the data.Data is also getting generated at runtime from data i am trying to generate an array in json

Comment: So just try to serialize them using `JsonOutput.toJson(data)`

Comment: its plain data .How do i conver that plain data in json?

Comment: response=[
PackageName:packages
,
PackageVersion:version,
DeployTime:deployedon,
DeployedBy:deployedby
] I am using something like this now.But using this only one element  is being added .I cannot add multiple elements

Comment: my json should have [{package:"abc",version:"v1"},{package:"xyz",version:"v2"}]                                               What i can achieve now is response=[
PackageName:"abc"
,
PackageVersion:v1,
]                                                                       However i am not able to add package2 and version 2                      As this data is in a list I am iterating through the list.Json should get created as i iterate the list

Comment: `[{package:"abc",version:"v1"},{package:"xyz",version:"v2"}]` is the data You are getting? In plain text or variable in groovy? Edit the question and provide a full example with desired output.

Comment: i need to create a json of [{package:"abc",version:"v1"},{package:"xyz",version:"v2"}] type from plain data i am receiving from the list as i am iterating the list

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear. What is the type of the list You getting? String?

Comment: @kais could you please add all this information to your original question instead of plastering it all in comments?